# How do I fill a vector with a void function in C++

Tags: c++, function, void

How do I fill a vector with a void function in C++.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
void Fill_Vec(vector<int> vec, int n){
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    cin>>vec[i];
   }
}

int main(){

int n;
int i;
cin>>n;
vector<int> vec;
Fill_Vec(vec, n);
}
```

this Doesn't seem to work, I just learned functions so I'm struggling a bit.

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking

Comment: You are passing a copy of the vector.

Comment: It seems to be perfectly working to me. Not that useful, but working.
Probably you wanna read about `reference` btw

Comment: I know its not useful, but I need to make a function, the thing is it works without errors but whenether I define n and try to fill the vector after inputting just one number it just stops.

Comment: You'll also need to allocate the space required in your `std::vector` if you want to index into it like you're currently doing.

Comment: I voted to reopen as the linked question will not completely solve the OP's problem.

Comment: @WBuck well, actually he asked about vector in function. What you, correctly, noticed would have been a problem even outside a function. Probably the OP needs to study in general how this language works.

Comment: @Federico my problem had a very simple fix to it, I don't know why your going overboard with the question, I am forced to make a function which fills a vector(currently learning C++), and instead of answering the question your doing everything to close the question. the only thing I wanted to do is to create a function which fills a vector, thats it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a reference parameter with a &

`void Fill_Vec(vector<int>& vec, int n)`

Comment: I did change that, but still does the same.

Comment: @SuperPOTATO Look at the comment I made. You need to both pass a reference of the `std::vector` to the function as well as allocate enough space in the `std::vector` if you want to index into it. Or you can use `push_back` instead. For example, `int value = 0; std::cin >> value; vec.push_back( value );`